# Safari saves only one of “Set-Cookie” headers

Tags: node.js, azure, cookies, safari, csrf

I'm using the node.js server with the csurf library and it's hosted on Microsoft Azure. The csurf library sends a response cookie with a x-csrf-token, but it is not saved in Safari.

Also in every response Azure sends an ARRAffinity cookie which is properly saved in Safari.

Is it some bug in Safari/Csurf and only one cookie is saved, or can I change it somehow?